# Download not showing file size to be downloaded in Liferay portlet

Tags: java, http-headers, download, liferay-6

I am using serveResource to allow download files of document library through my portlet.

I have also mentioned `Content_Length` parameter in code:

```
res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(zipFileLength));
```

Here, `res` is ResourceResponse.

However, it only shows the downloaded size but not the size to be downloaded.

This code is working in Mozilla, mozilla is showing total file size and size of data downloaded , but not in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Comment: I don't understand : do you mean you can see the full size only with firefox ? Please edit your questions in order to clarify this point. Also, for your information, you can format code in your questions (and answers). I already did this, but it's good to know :)

Comment: thanks for formatting.
Yes Mozilla is showing total size of downloading file.